# Uninstalling Patches from list of Machines

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that pulls from a list of machines and uninstalls hotfixes listed below. I can't seem to find the right cmdlet as it says -HotfixID is not a cmdlet. Can anyone help me out with this.

```
$myComputers = Get-Content

"c:\mycomputers.txt"
foreach ($computer in $myComputers) {
Uninstall-HotFix -ComputerName $computer

-HotfixID KB123456
-HotfixID KB925673

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the command for each hotfix like so:

```
$myComputers = Get-Content "c:\mycomputers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $myComputers) {
  Uninstall-HotFix -ComputerName $computer -HotfixID KB123456
  Uninstall-HotFix -ComputerName $computer -HotfixID KB925673

}
```